# JavaFX CSS image not rendering

Tags: css, url, gradle, javafx

I am working on a Gradle JavaFX project in IntelliJ.  My question is essentially "How do I get a background-image URL working for JavaFX in CSS?" for which the answer would be:

```
.button{
    -fx-background-image: url("/image/CloseButtonBlack.png");
}
```

except that this doesn't work for me.  After much experimentation, I have discovered that if I move the file up one level so it lies directly in the resources folder, everything works.  Because of this, I believe that the reason the file doesn't display when it lies within the image folder is that the image folder is not marked as a resource folder.  If I were not using Gradle, I believe I could fix this just by using IntelliJ's Project Structure -> Modules menu.  Since I am using Gradle though, I am thinking that the correct way to fix this would be to write some code in build.gradle so that Gradle knows the image folder is a resource folder.  If I am right, what code is it that I need to write to get my background image to display while it lies in the image folder?

[image]

Comment: I could be wrong, but it looks to me like your path is incorrect. Your main.css file is located in your style folder and you dont have an image folder inside of your style folder, meaning that you need to go back one step and then point to the image folder. Try "../image/CloseButtonBlack.png".

Comment: I believe the path is correct.  If I try "../something", I believe that will refer to the "src/something" folder.  When I move the images out of the image folder and into the resource folder, all I have to do is change the path to "/CloseButtonBlack.png".  Another way to test this is to refactor -> move files.  Intellij will automatically change the path using the "../" way instead of the resource folder way.  I believe just putting the "/" in front of the path will just access the resource folder.

Comment: My fonts behave in the same way as my images.  Neither will work unless they are directly in "/filename".  I suppose then an obvious solution might be to try to use the "../" way, but then wouldn't that be ignoring the idea of a resource folder?

Comment: Well I am just assuming now, but I would have thought that since the paths are written in the CSS file they would have to be the written relative to the location of the CSS file. I would not say that it would be ignoring the idea of a resources folder, no. I would say that writing paths in CSS and loading a resource though Java code are two different things. Again though, I am just assuming and I have never worked in IntelliJ. Im writing this on my Phone so there might be a bunch of misspelled or autocorrcted words, but I hope you figure things out. Happy new year :)